# Why does my Authorisation header disappear when using stream_get_contents?

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a request using PHP's `stream_get_contents` mechanism since I don't have CURL. This request works fine locally but when deployed to a remote server doesn't send all the headers. Here's the PHP snippet:

```
<?php
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => array(
            'Content-type: application/json',
            'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode('username:secret'),
        ),
        'content' => json_encode(array(
            'key' => 'value',
        )),
    )
));
file_get_contents('http://requestb.in/xxxxxx', false, $context);
?>
```

When this is executed from my local machine, I see the following headers as received by the server:

```
Via: 1.1 vegur
Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6c2VjcmV0
Host: requestb.in
Content-Length: 70
Total-Route-Time: 0
Content-Type: application/json
X-Request-Id: a2cf10d8-a82a-4302-897f-3f40daa22028
Connect-Time: 1
Connection: close
```

...and here's what I get when I execute the snippet from the remote server.

```
User-Agent: PHP/5.2.17
Host: requestb.in
Via: 1.1 vegur
X-Request-Id: 14e7af5f-39aa-474a-8d1a-af992997d0ef
Content-Length: 70
Total-Route-Time: 0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*
Connect-Time: 7
Connection: close
```

The content-length is different because I've modified my pOST request's payload but as you can see, I can't get the `Authorisation` header in the second scenario and the `Content-Type` header has changed too.

I'm really lost with this and haven't found an explanation for this quirky behaviour. (I'm using RequestBin to simply help me troubleshoot the issue.)

Comment: In both scenarios, are you running that via PHP?

Comment: I'm not running that via the CLI (if that's what you meant), it's a PHP script that I'm running on Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If php is compiled using flag "--with-curlwrappers", then this issue might be due to a bug in php.
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55438

Answer (score 0):

The `'header'` key in your context array must be a string. See the example in [PHP docs here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php)

```
$method = 'GET';
$contextOptions = array(
    'http'  => array(
        'method'    => $method,
        'header'    => array(
            'X-Forwarded-For: ' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
            'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($apiKey . ':' . $flags),
        ),
    )
);

if ('POST' === $method || 'GET' === $method) {
    $contextOptions['http']['header'][] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
} elseif ('PUT' === $method || 'UPDATE' === $method) {
    $contextOptions['http']['header'][] = 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream';
}

$contextOptions['http']['header'][] = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data);
$contextOptions['http']['content'] = $data;
$contextOptions['http']['header'] = implode("\r\n", $contextOptions['http']['header']);
```

Comment: I've tried both but it doesn't seem to work. As you can see the PHP version the server is running is 5.2.17 and since 5.2.10, the `header` can be a numerically indexed array as you can see from the changelog here http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php

Comment: Indexed arrays never worked for me. I've edited my answer with some code I use in a project

Comment: I tried your snippet and the headers were still stripped out. I can't see the `Authorization` header. I forgot to mention that this code works as expected from another server but this particular server removes the header.

Answer (score 0):

Is your main problem that the Authorization header is missing?  I had a similar problem which was resolved by editing the .htaccess file as follows:

```
 
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.)
    RewriteRule . - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```